# Find Decimal Place and Use this in Calculations

Tags: ms-access

I am looking to write a query in Access that finds a decimal place and then uses the data after to make some calculations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: may be it is better to provide an example?

Comment: I have a range of numbers in the following format 22.23; 26; 98.36 etc etc.  I want to find the decimal and then *12.

Comment: Which type they are? Text or Float

Answer (score 1):

May this be answer?:

```
SELECT [number],  [number]-fix([number]) AS [DECIMAL_part] FROM [TMP_TABLE]
```

Comment: Note "The difference between Int and Fix functions is that if Number is negative, Int returns the first negative integer less than or equal to Number, whereas Fix returns the first negative integer greater than or equal to Number. For example, Int converts -8.4 to -9, and Fix converts -8.4 to -8." http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/int-fix-functions-HA001228859.aspx

Comment: you are right, that is why i had used "Fix" : -8.4-fix(-8.4) will return -0.4.    But may be "Abs" is required to get rid of "-" sign.

Comment: I created the following which seems to work fine AGE YEARS MONTHS: IIf([Date of Birth] Is Not Null,Int([DECIMAL AGE]) & "." & Int(([DECIMAL AGE]-Int([DECIMAL AGE]))*12),"*****")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select MyNumber, Trim(Right(Trim(MyNumber), Len(Trim(MyNumber))-InStr(MyNumber, "."))) 
AS DecNumber, Trim(Right(Trim(MyNumber), Len(Trim(MyNumber))-InStr(MyNumber, "."))) * 12 
AS NewValue FROM MyTable
```